# Using res.sendStatus(200) with JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a form with an onsubmit function that includes an ajax call to the backend, which is Node + Express.

On successful submission, I send `res.sendStatus(200)` to the client. The response, in the network console, registers as an `OK`. How do I capture this success in the AJAX method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `status()` and `send()`:

```
res.status(200).send({ success: true })
```

Comment: I think is that you need to send at least an object in the response in order to jquery control the callback, is that?